# Animation is not eased-out

Tags: css, sass, css-animations, css-transitions

I have such code and somehow `ease-out` doesn't seem to work. Is there anything with `animation` property that prevents it from working?

```css
.fade-in-header-button
    opacity: 0
    animation: slideInFromBottom .25s ease-out .25s 1 forwards

  @keyframes slideInFromBottom
    0%
      opacity: 0
      transform: translateY(150%)
    100%
      opacity: 1
      transform: translateY(0)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this demo.

Make CSS to formatting properly..

with semi-column and brackets (`;` and `{}`).

```css
.fade-in-header-button{
  border:none;
  padding:10px 20px;
  background:#00cc00;
  color:#fff;
  opacity: 0;
  animation: slideInFromBottom .25s ease-out .25s 1 forwards;
}
@keyframes slideInFromBottom{
  0%{
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(150%);
  }
  100%{
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}
```

```html
<button class="fade-in-header-button">Slide In From Bottom</button>
```

About **[ease-out, ease-in and ease-in-out](https://css-tricks.com/ease-out-in-ease-in-out/)**

Comment: Are you want like this? if any changes i would happy to change the answer too. btw thanks :)

Comment: This is still going `linear` where I want it to be `ease-out`ed :) I look for smooth animation. Also I use `.sass` format - that's why I don't have `;` nor `{}`.

Comment: still no luck :/

Comment: you can change the ease-out by try like [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qYRX5.png) click the circle to change animation as your needs.